# How can I fix the "Debug Assertion Failure" exception in C++ (VS 2019), guys?

Tags: visual-c++, unicode, assertion

Here's my codes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <codecvt>
#include <locale>
#pragma warning (disable:4996)
using namespace std;

int main() {
    FILE* fd;
    fd = fopen("VN.txt", "a");
    int ngu, dumb;
    ngu = _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U8TEXT);
    dumb =_setmode(_fileno(fd), _O_U8TEXT);
    locale loc(locale(), new codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>);
    wifstream out(L"VN.txt");
    fstream ENi("EN.txt", ios::in);
    fstream ENo("EN.txt", ios::app);
    fstream ENi2("EN2.txt", ios::in);
    fstream ENo2("EN2.txt", ios::app);
    fstream so("Num.txt", ios::in);
    int num;
    so >> num;
    int quit = 0;
    char EN[100];
    wchar_t VN[100];
    while (quit != 5) {
        cout << "Pick a number:" << endl;
        cout << "1. Add a word" << endl;
        cout << "2. Translate a word using data from this program" << endl;
        cout << "3. Add the missing meaning for a word" << endl;
        cout << "4. Test your memory with random words from this dictionary" << endl;
        cout << "5. Exit" << endl;
        cin >> quit;
        switch (quit) {
        case 1: {
            cout << "Please type the word you want to add:" << endl;
            cin.getline(EN, 100);
            exit;
            num++;
            cout << "Please type its meaning, if you have no idea, please type 'idk'" << endl;
            wcin.getline(VN, 100);
            if (VN != L"idk") {
                ENo2 << EN << endl;
                fprintf(fd, "%ws \n", VN);
            }
            else {
                ENo2 << EN << endl;
            }
            ENi.seekp(ios::beg);
            ENi2.seekp(ios::beg);
            ENo.seekp(ios::beg);
            ENo2.seekp(ios::beg);
        }
        case 2: {
            cout << "What word would you like to translate?" << endl;
            cin.getline(EN, 100);
            string EN2;
            wstring VN2;
            int check = 0;
            while (!ENi.eof()) {
                ENi >> EN2;
                out.imbue(loc); //đọc TV
                getline(out, VN2);
                if (EN2 == EN) {
                    check = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (check == 1)
                wcout << "According to this dictionary, the meaning of this word is: " << VN2 << endl;
            if (check == 0) {
                int mode;
                cout << "This word haven't been added to your dictionary yet" << endl;
                cout << "Add it now?" << endl;
                cout << "1. Yes" << endl << "2. No" << endl;
                cin >> mode;
                switch (mode) {
                case 1: {
                    ENo << EN;
                    cout << "Please type its meaning, if you have no idea, please type 'idk'" << endl;
                    wcin.getline(VN, 100);
                    if (VN != L"idk") {
                        ENo << EN << endl;
                        fprintf(fd, "%ws \n", VN);
                    }
                    else {
                        ENo2 << EN << endl;
                    }
                }
                case 2: {
                    break;
                }
                }
            }
            ENi.seekp(ios::beg);
            ENi2.seekp(ios::beg);
            ENo.seekp(ios::beg);
            ENo2.seekp(ios::beg);
        }
        case 3: {
            cout << "Preparing..." << endl << "Please wait..." << endl;
            string EN2;
            wstring VN2;
            int check = 0;
            int dem = 0;
            while (!ENi2.eof()) {
                ENi2 >> EN2;
                dem++;
            }
            if (dem == 0) {
                cout << "There's no words without meanings in your dictionary" << endl;
                break;
            }
            string** idk = new string * [dem];
            for (int i = 0; i < dem; i++) {
                idk[i] = new string;
            }
            if (dem != 0) {
                ENi2.seekp(ios::beg);
                dem = 0;
                while (!ENi2.eof()) {
                    ENi2 >> idk[dem][0];
                    dem++;
                }
            }
            cout << "Please add the meaning of these below words, if you still have no idea, please type 'idk'" << endl;
            for (int i = 0; i < dem; i++) {
                cout << idk[i][0];
                wcin.getline(VN, 100);
                if (VN != L"idk") {
                    fprintf(fd, "%ws", VN);
                    ENo << idk[i][0];
                    delete idk[i];
                }
            }
            fstream ENo3("EN2.txt", ios::out);
            for (int i = 0; i < dem; i++) {
                ENo3 << idk[i][0];
            }
            ENi.seekp(ios::beg);
            ENi2.seekp(ios::beg);
            ENo.seekp(ios::beg);
            ENo2.seekp(ios::beg);
        }
        case 4: {
            break;
        }
        default: {
            break;
        }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I was trying to write a program which can add new English words from the users with their Vietnamese meanings and translate English words using data from the program's text files like "EN.txt" and "VN.txt". Also, you can add new English words without meanings and complete their meanings later.
Everything was fine, my VS reported no issues like the picture below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dbrt6.png)
However, when I started to debug, this exception appeared:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSiEk.png)

Comment: You can't open the same file twice. E.g. after `fstream ENi("EN.txt", ios::in); fstream ENo("EN.txt", ios::app);` I expect `ENo.fail()` to be true, and any attempt to actually use `ENo` is likely failing.

Comment: Thx u, I forgot to check if the file is open

Comment: Actually, those files were opened successfully